# Future of complexity classes in case NP=P

Tags: soft-question, computational-complexity

The P=NP question is still unresolved and there is no hope that the situation will ever change.

Assume now the hypothetic situation that P=NP had been confirmed:

**Questions:**

- what will become of the complexity classes that were identified when P=NP was still open?
- Will they then identify different realms or hierarchies of the efficiently solvable problems?
- Do such hierarchies, apart from the time complexity, already exist, i.e. are bipartite matching and general matching in different realms of the efficiently solvable problems?
- We can solve unmodified bipartite matching problem instances  with any algorithm for general matching but not vice versa; can that asymmetry in the ability to solve unmodified problem instances of other problems serve as a criterion for defining hierarchies within the class P?

Comment: This seems like a pretty broad question. There must be hundreds of papers written about consequences of P=NP.

Comment: "The P=NP question is still unresolved and there is no hope that the situation will ever change." There is always hope.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "there must hundreds of papers...":  could you provide links to serious ones?

Comment: (I believe that last comment was directed at me, not Gerry...) Maybe for a start of implications of P=NP, look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35759/what-would-be-the-real-world-implications-of-a-constructive-p-np-proof.

Comment: But when I said there must be many papers about consequences of P=NP, really what I had in mind was that one strategy to show P != NP would be to assume P=NP and reach a contradiction; hence, there is interest in showing implausible things follow from P=NP (for example, the collapse of the polynomial hierarchy- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy).

Comment: @SamHopkins sorry for misadressing my request for links. I have checked the linked resources, but they don't address my question. The first one discusses the implikations on the real world and the Wikipedia article explains the existing polynomial hierarchy but not the effects of P=NP on that hierarchy, except maybe that it NP would tumble down to P. My question is however more aimed at whether anyone would then still classify problems that are the in P as "would have been NP-complete, would have had a PTAS, etc"